# Javascript: DOM moving element to verticle middle

Tags: javascript, dom, center

The thing it is suppose to center winds up being way low, not in the vertical middle. Then if I resize or call the function later it works.

```
function fixstuff () {
    //document.getElementById("WElogo").style.zIndex = "10000";
    document.getElementById("WEmiddle").style.top = window.innerHeight / 2 - (document.getElementById("WEmiddle").clientHeight / 2) + "px";
}

//setTimeout(fixstuff, 2000); //<-- this works

fixstuff(); // <--- this dont

window.onresize = fixstuff;
```

Comment: is that function call inside DOM ready? if not, put that inside DOM ready and check again

Comment: This is generally not how you'd want to go about vertically centering an element. Have you tried `top: 50%; transform: translateY(-50%);`?